# jQuery find element und get content of title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with some jQuery code and I don't know why it doesn't work.
I try to find a list element with a special class definition.
This "li" element will have 2 childrens, which are "a" statements.
One of this "a" statements will have an "title" attribute and I need the text of this "title" attribute.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var description;
var element;
element = jQuery('li.category_8');
description = element.find('title').attr('title');
jQuery('span.category_desc').html(description);
</script>
```

I don't know why the variable named "description" is undefined ... do you have an idea?

Jens

Comment: That's nice that you're using 'jQuery' instead of '$' ;)

Comment: can you give your html code...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code within document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//your code here

});
```

---

And this is wrong:

```
description = element.find('title').attr('title');
```

Do like this:

```
description = element.find([attr='title']);
```

title element is only within head not in li

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li .category_8 a[title]").attr('title')
```

This will find `title` of `a` element inside `li` which have `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is little wrong, you are finding an element which have a tagname of `title` so instead of it you have to change it little bit like this: `.find('a[title]')` as suggested to change.

change this:

```
description = element.find('title').attr('title');
```

to this:

```
var description = $('li.category_8').find('a[title]').attr('title');
```

---

The above line returns title for `a` which contains `title` attribute.

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfKbv/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="lists">
    <li><a href="a" title="xyz">linkText</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery Code To get title of a;

```
$(".lists").find("li a").attr('title');
```